# jQuery Mobile - Change Background Color Based on WebService Call

Tags: jquery, css, cordova, jquery-mobile

I've got a Phonegap app running jQuery Mobile. I want to be able to make slight modifications to the page based on calls to my webservice.

I have three columns each with their own color:

```
    <div data-role="page" id="columns">
      <div data-role="header"><h1>Columns</h1></div>
      <div class="col" style="background-color: purple"></div>
      <div class="col" style="background-color: red"></div>
      <div class="col" style="background-color: black"></div>
    </div><!-- page -->
```

A response from my API (i.e. myapi.example.com/?bg-color) would be a hex code (#0066FF).

**How can I update the background-color of each individual column to reflect the webservice values?**

Comment: using classes would make your life so much easier, none the less, look here: http://api.jquery.com/css/ (`$(element).css('background-color', myApiResponse)`)

Comment: but the dom is fetched all togehter in jquery-mobile. How do I update the background-color value when "columns" is  loaded?

Comment: You might want to show an example of the response you are getting from the server

Answer (score 0):

you can change background color using web-services but it's some slow process.your webservices color response store into one globar variable or in localhost look bellow example.

```
<script>
     document.body.style.backgroundColor = // Your global variable  //"#AA0000";
</script>
```

your webservices call inside onpage load function so when page load at time function load and fatch background-color from webservices and set in body background.

Comment: This is jQuery mobile. You need to account for the pagecontainer load.

Answer (score 0):

When the AJAX call is complete, get the columns and set the background-color CSS style to the returned color:

```
$(document).on("pagecreate","#columns", function(){ 
    $("#btn").on("click", function(){   
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://echo.jsontest.com/color1/orange/color2/blue/color3/green",
        }).done(function(response) {
            var columns = $("div.col");
            columns.eq(0).css('background-color', response.color1);
            columns.eq(1).css('background-color', response.color2);
            columns.eq(2).css('background-color', response.color3);
        });        
    });
});
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/7x0q93zL/)**